# how to pass args for archive.php query?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, templates, archives, archive-template

I am trying to pass args to archive.php so that I can order the posts, set the number of posts, etc..

but the query is done like this

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()): the_post();?>
```

if it was`new \WP_Query($args);` i was able to pass the args here but this can't be done in archive.php template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pre_get_posts` hook can be used to modify queries before they're run. You can use `$query->set()` to set arguments on the `WP_Query` object, and `$query->is_main_query()` in the callback to limit your changes to the main query:

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
        }
    }
);
```

You can't target specific *templates*, but if you want the change to only affect archives, you can use `$query->is_archive()`, which will be true for date, taxonomy and post type archives, or if you only want to apply the changes to the category archives, you can use `$query->is_category()`. Many of the normal [conditional functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) are available as methods for checking the current query.

Comment: thank you. Just having doubt in default how WordPress decides the order for its archives?

Comment: Everything’s ordered by date by default. Same as the normal blog.

Answer (score -1):

this is the code from my archive.php file:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$myposts = new WP_Query($args);

<?php if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else: ?>

    //If there is no post for this category / tag

<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope I understood the question well and that I can help you.

Best regards.

Comment: yes. but how can i pass args to this query? Say if i wanted to order them by title and show only 3 posts with pagination?

Comment: I updated the answer, could this work for you?

Comment: if you change it like that it will become a new loop. archive.php will show the same result for all archives.

Comment: Can you better explain the result you would like to achieve? Unfortunately I don't understand English very well.

Comment: you can't put `new WP_Query($args);` in `archive.php ` it works without it.  I am just checking if there is any method to pass $args to this loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046134/using-paginate-links-on-post-archive-page this is my answer :). thanks for looking into it

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your request. I hope you have solved your problem...